# Boolean attributes in htmltools tags

Tags: r, htmltools

I can create an HTML `option` tag using

```
htmltools::tags$option("abc", value = 1)
```

and I get

```
<option value="1">abc</option>
```

But how do I add the boolean attribute `selected` to it, to get

```
<option value="1" selected>abc</option>
```

?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in [a suggestion](https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/issues/81) by nteetor on the `htmltools` Github page:

```
htmltools::tags$option("abc", value = 1, selected = NA)
```

gives me

```
<option value="1" selected>abc</option>
```